# I cannot launch Apache Web UI after clicking the Monitor icon in ADF. 401 error

Tags: airflow, azure-data-factory

I cannot launch Apache Web UI after clicking the Monitor icon in Azure Data Factory.
Within the "Manage" tab within ADF I have created an Airflow. Its status is "Running".
When I click on the "Import files" icon I was able to import and select folders  okay.
But when I click on the Monitor icon next to it, I am directed to a new web page with "Unauthorised 401" error on it.
In the MSFT docs it states and shows I should be directed to the Apache Airflow Web UI page instead. Azure AD is integrated with that service, apparently.
In the screenshot you can see I have two Airflow instances and you can see the "Import files" and monitor icons. It is the monitor icon button, here, that is sending me to the error message.
[the Monitor icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrrqY.png)

I was expecting to be sent to the Apache Airflow Web UI page.

[Azure Managed Apache Airflow Web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0cNK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also tried in my environment, and it is working fine for me.

- Created Airflow in Azure data factory.
  [image]
- I am getting directed to the Apache Airflow Web UI page.
  [image]

Try with **enabling** `Preview Experience` **this option is to try new features. Some examples of what is currently in preview.**

[image]

As this feature is in public preview and issue still persist. You can raise support ticket to Microsoft from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) for more assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

i tried it in my tenant, when i use the AAd Auth, it does not work , i also get the error of unauthorized, so i do it with the basic auth where:
client id = username = application id (check for it in azure active directory, click on app registration -> in overview tab under Application (client) ID
and the password should be : in azure active directory -> app regeneration -> overview tab -> see Client credentials and retrive secret.
make sure to make azure data factory connection in your airflow ui so you'll get to run pipelines from ADF.

Comment: Now its fixed with the AAD auth, i tried it yesterday and it worked.